# Evidence for the authenticity of relics relics such as the True Cross?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, relics

I'm wondering if there is any evidence for the authenticity of various relics such as pieces of the "true cross".

Comment: I added the **Catholicism** tag to your question, as relics of the true Cross usually come from Rome.